# QGIS plugin Red layer not active

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to use the new plugin [Red Layer](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/redLayer/), I have installed it in QGIS ver. 2.81. I can open the menu but it is not active. How do I enable it?

[image: Plugin Red Layer]

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with 2.8.2.  Make sure that your project file is writeable.  Mine was read only, also try restarting QGIS.

I found the tool is disabled for Read-Only project files or if the I haven't created a project file and works when the project file exists and is writeable.

Comment: I have installed QGIS ver-2.8.2 and plugin red layer now is active.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem in 2.14.5 LTR. I figured out that even when saving the project the plugin is inaccessible. The project needs to be saved, then exit QGIS and restart it with the latter project. Then the plugin can be used in the usual way.